# WPF ListView proprties disable line and change color

Tags: wpf, listview

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid{ get; set; }
}
```

---

```
List<Foo> myFoos = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo() { Name = "one", IsValid = true },
    new Foo() { Name = "Two", IsValid = false },
    new Foo() { Name = "Three", IsValid = true }
};

lvFoos.Items.Add(myFoos);
```

---

```
<ListView x:Name="lvFoos" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View >
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Hi I have a list of foos and I would like to add them all to my listview in my WPF project.
if my foo is not valid, I would like to disable the option to choose him, yet possible to make other foos selectable.
I would also want to make the option clear to the user this foo is invalid, maybe make the text red or something.
How do I do that? even though its very basic stuff, didn't find simple instructions on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by creating a `Style` that targets `ListBoxItem` and assign it to the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` property. Use triggers to change appearance based on conditions:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Name" 
                      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>

  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValid}"
                     Value="False">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                  Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

By default disabled items (or controls in general) appear grey and are not selectable/hit test visible. So there already is a visual feedback. If you want to change the color of disabled items from grey to e.g. red you would have to override the default `ListBoxItem.Template` too. Same is if you want to change the highlight color or background of the items.